# What can I do about a "500 SSH not understood" error?

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh

Relating to this [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280719/sftp-access-to-osx-stopped-working) about `sftp`ing files between Android and OSX, I'd like to know under what conditions an SFTP server responds with `500 SSH-2.0-<client program> not understood`. 
On the OSX command line, I type

```
sftp -oport=<port> <user>@<ip>
```

but on the Android side I get

```
500 SSH-2.0-OPENSSH_7.4 not understood
```

What configurations do I need to make in order to connect to an SFTP server running on Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**That's not an SFTP server.** That's an FTP server. While the names may be similar, those are two entirely different and unrelated protocols.

- FTP is a plain line-based protocol.
- FTPS is "regular" FTP but uses TLS (SSL) as the transport.
- SFTP uses SSH as the transport, and is very different on the inside as well.

FTP uses plain 4-letter commands (e.g. `USER`, `FEAT`) and numeric success/error responses. Meanwhile, all SSH and SFTP clients (and servers) start with a `SSH-2.0-[clientname]` header and speak a binary protocol afterwards.

Some clients (WinSCP, FileZilla, lftp) support all three, but you must correctly tell them which one to use. The `sftp` command, meanwhile, is for SFTP only and you cannot use it with a FTP server.

Comment: Ok, how could it be that I could access this very server with FileZilla via SFTP until recently?

Comment: Maybe you had configured FileZilla to use FTP and not SFTP, or maybe the server had protocol auto-detection at some point in time? The fact remains that you're _not_ connecting to a SFTP-compatible server right now.

Comment: Using the *HTTPS / FTPS / SFTP* App for android, I can start a guaranteed SFTP server, but connecting like above results in `Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.2 port 2222: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss`. What do I need to do for password authentication? I have configured credentials in the server app.

Comment: I also can't use the `ftp` command line client from OSX, the server doesn't even report any attempts in the log. But using ftp instead of sftp form FileZilla appears to work. So your suggestion that FileZilla stopped doing some kind of autodetect seems reasonable. I still don't get why I'm not able to access the SFTP server running on the Computer from Android, however.

Comment: FileZilla definitely does not do any protocol autodetection.

Comment: For the "Unable to negotiate with ... " error - Show us `sftp -v` output.

Comment: Though, it's for a new question. Your original question has been answered already.